# Use matlab to search excel data file for time range and copy data into variable

Tags: excel, matlab, datetime, xlsread

In my excel file I have a time column in 12 hr clock time and a bunch of data columns. I have pasted a snippet of it in this post as a code since i cant attach a file. I am trying to build a gui that will take an input from the user like so:

start time: 7:29:32 AM

End time: 7:29:51 AM

Then do the following:

calculate the time that has passed in seconds (should be just a row count, data is gathered once a second)

copy the data in the time range from the "Data 3" column in to a variable perform other calculations on the data copied as needed

I am having some trouble figuring out what to do to search the time data and find its location since it imports as text with xlsread. any ideas?

The data looks like this:

```
Time        Data 1      Data 2      Data 3      Data 4      Data 5
7:29:25 AM  0.878556385 0.388400561 0.076890401 0.93335277  0.884750618
7:29:26 AM  0.695838393 0.712762566 0.014814069 0.81264949  0.450303694
7:29:27 AM  0.250846937 0.508617941 0.24802015  0.722457624 0.47119616
7:29:28 AM  0.206189924 0.82970364  0.819163787 0.060932817 0.73455323
7:29:29 AM  0.161844331 0.768214077 0.154097877 0.988201094 0.951520263
7:29:30 AM  0.704242494 0.371877481 0.944482485 0.79207359  0.57390951
7:29:31 AM  0.072028024 0.120263127 0.577396985 0.694153791 0.341824004
7:29:32 AM  0.241817775 0.32573323  0.484644494 0.377938298 0.090122672
7:29:33 AM  0.500962945 0.540808907 0.582958676 0.043377373 0.041274613
7:29:34 AM  0.087742217 0.596508236 0.020250297 0.926901109 0.45960323
7:29:35 AM  0.268222071 0.291034947 0.598887588 0.575571111 0.136424853
7:29:36 AM  0.42880255  0.349597405 0.936733938 0.232128788 0.555528823
7:29:37 AM  0.380425154 0.162002488 0.208550466 0.776866494 0.79340504
7:29:38 AM  0.727940393 0.622546124 0.716007768 0.660480612 0.02463804
7:29:39 AM  0.582772435 0.713406643 0.306544291 0.225257421 0.043552277
7:29:40 AM  0.371156954 0.163821476 0.780515577 0.032460418 0.356949005
7:29:42 AM  0.484167263 0.377878242 0.044189636 0.718147456 0.603177625
7:29:43 AM  0.294017186 0.463360581 0.962296024 0.504029061 0.183131098
7:29:44 AM  0.95635086  0.367849494 0.362230918 0.984421096 0.41587606
7:29:45 AM  0.198645523 0.754955312 0.280338922 0.79706146  0.730373691
7:29:46 AM  0.058483961 0.46774544  0.86783339  0.147418954 0.941713252
7:29:47 AM  0.411193343 0.340857813 0.162066261 0.943124515 0.722124394
7:29:48 AM  0.389312994 0.129281042 0.732723258 0.803458815 0.045824426
7:29:49 AM  0.549633038 0.73956852  0.542532728 0.618321989 0.358525184
7:29:50 AM  0.269925317 0.501399748 0.938234302 0.997577871 0.318813506
7:29:51 AM  0.798825842 0.24038537  0.958224157 0.660124357 0.07469288
7:29:52 AM  0.963581196 0.390150081 0.077448543 0.294604314 0.903519943
7:29:53 AM  0.890540963 0.50284339  0.229976565 0.664538451 0.926438543
7:29:54 AM  0.46951573  0.192568637 0.506730373 0.060557482 0.922857391
7:29:55 AM  0.56552394  0.952136998 0.739438663 0.107518765 0.911045415
7:29:56 AM  0.433149875 0.957190309 0.475811126 0.855705733 0.942255155
```

and this is the code I am using:

```
[Data,Text] = xlsread('C:\Users\data.xlsx',2); 
IndexStart=strmatch('7:29:29 AM',Text,'exact');   %start time 
IndexEnd=strmatch('2:30:29 PM',Text,'exact');     %end time 
seconds = IndexEnd-IndexStart; 
TestData = Data([IndexStart: IndexEnd],:);
```

Comment: Start with [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) to convert your time strings & user inputs to numeric values.

Comment: i left them as strings and just found their row numbers. if i subtract one from that value it will give me the right data point in the data column since the text headings are missing on my xlsread data matrix so everythign is shifted up one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to:

- Use `strfind` to find the relevant string in the data imported
- Use `datenum` to convert the date to serial date numbers, to be able to calculate the elapsed time between the two points.

It would help if you posted your code so far though.

**EDIT based on comments:**

Here's what I would do for cycling through the list of start and end times:

```
[Data,Text] = xlsread('C:\Users\data.xlsx',2); 
start_times = {'7:29:29 AM','7:29:35 AM','7:29:44 AM','7:29:49 AM'}; % etc...
end_times = {'2:30:29 PM','2:30:59 PM','2:31:22 PM','2:32:49 PM'}; % etc...
elapsed_time = zeros(length(start_times),1);
TestData = cell(length(start_times),1); % need a cell array because data can/will be of unequal lengths
for k=1:length(start_times)
    IndexStart=strmatch(start_times{k},Text,'exact');   %start time 
    IndexEnd=strmatch(end_times{k},Text,'exact');     %end time 
    elapsed_time(k) = IndexEnd-IndexStart; 
    TestData{k} = Data([IndexStart: IndexEnd],:);
end
```

Comment: I think have some idea of what to do now using the strfind: here is what I did: `IndexText=strfind(Text,'7:29:29')`followed by `Index = find(not(cellfun('isempty',IndexText)))` this gives me the row number of that time stamp. How do i take this and then tell matlab to select that row number in column 3 from the data set of values? and then tell it to select until the range for the end time which is stored as another row number index variable?

Comment: I think i figured that other part out too. I did `dataspan=Data([IndexStart:IndexEnd],:)` Where Indexstart and indexend were my start and stop time row numbers. is what I have done the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: You really need to post your code if you want us to help you further.

Comment: the code is still really simple but does what I need it to do: `[Data,Text] = xlsread('C:\Users\data.xlsx',2);

IndexStart=strmatch('7:29:29 AM',Text,'exact'); %start time
IndexEnd=strmatch('2:30:29 PM',Text,'exact'); %end time

seconds = IndexEnd-IndexStart;
TestData = Data([IndexStart: IndexEnd],:); `

Comment: so i will need to do this for 15 sections of data, is there a way to tell it to cycle through a list of times for each start/end span without just copy pasting the same 3 lines 15 times over? basically I will have 30 boxes on a gui for string input of the start and end time, the user uploads their data file with this table format and then hits go and it sifts through the data for those 15 segments, does some calcs on them and maybe spits out a graph with some labels. so i was basically going to replace the '2:30:29 PM' string in the strmatch with the get.handles....etc from my gui script.

Comment: I have edited my answer, hopefully that will illustrate the point for doing this for a number of start/end times.

Comment: So things are going well but I am running into a problem. If there is nothing in my gui string input box, it returns an empty string (obviously). What I want this to do is report back 0 for the Index Start/End variables but instead it fills them with every blank cell position it finds becuase all of those are just empty strings. Which is what I would expect, but how do I avoid it? I've been trying if else statements all day and can't seem to figure out what to have it do if it finds that IndexStart = '' so that it doesnt freak out over not having a value.

Comment: It's difficult to comment without seeing the code for the GUI and would probably be better detailed in a new question, but something like `if isempty(string_input) IndexStart=0; else IndexStart=strmatch(start_times{k},Text,'exact');` should do the trick. As I said, probably best to accept my answer for this question (only if it solved your problem of course) create a new question, explaining the new issue in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Import Data" from the Variable Tag in the Home menu. There you can set how you want the data to be imported like. With or without heading and the format.